# login page doesn't read css in java ee application

Tags: css, jsp

I've created an application with form based log in but the login page doesn't appear to read the css and appears almost empty. Do you know what i may have done wrong?

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

```
<HEAD>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <TITLE>E-Health</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

    <div id="link3">
                        <a href="reg">Εγγραφή χρήστη</a>
    </div>


    <div align="center" id="main">

                <H1>Καλώς ήρθατε στο E-Health</H1>
                <p><img src="images/medlogo.jpg" alt="logo1" height="200" width="200" /></p>

                     <form action="j_security_check" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        <p>Nickname:<input type="text" name="j_username" size="15"></p>
                        <p>Password:<input type="password" name="j_password" size="15"></p>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Είσοδος">
                     </form>


    </div>
   <div id="footer">

Copyright © 2012 E-Health
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: and now i've just noticed that all the pages have the same problem. I couldn't have the security constraints work and now that i fixed the problem another one appeared! I have all the pages in WEB-INF/view folder except for index.jsp, login.jsp, loginError.html and style.css which are in WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to say without seeing a live example.

However, I would fully expect that the reason lies in a security exception: if your log-in page is under https but the CSS/assets aren't, some browsers will not load the (insecure) content, and you end up without any CSS/images.

Best bet would be to use NET in FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools to watch the traffic and see what error is being returned for the CSS.

One final possible issue: are you sure that it's correctly referencing the CSS file?  Ie: have you checked to make absolutely sure that it's linked correctly?

Comment: Everything is on http and all the pages were viewed correctly until i fixed the security constraints problem!

Comment: Hmm... Another thing is that index.jsp which is in WEB-INF folder and not in WEB-INF/view folder and is not protected is viewed correctly!

Comment: I fully expect that this is a security issue.  Take a look at the NET tab when you load the page.  I expect you're going to find that those assets (that fall outside the protected area) are returning 403.

Comment: When you say NET tab what exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, open up the Developer Tools (right-click on the page and hit 'inspect element'), then click on the "network' tab (third-from the right).  If you're using Firefox, use Firebug (you might need to install it first), and the tab in there is called 'NET' and it's sixth from the left.  With that open, hit refresh on your page.  It will show you all the network traffic as the page loads, and will show you what the returned status codes are for the page assets.

Comment: By everything i mean images!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was caused by this:  The "login-page" and "error-page" are presented by the server using the path to the constrained resource, not their actual paths, thus relative links to CSS and image files did not work reliably.

Example:

1. Stylesheet is /style.css
2. login page is /login.jsp
3. login.jsp links to relative path "style.css"
4. I try to access the protected URL /protected/foo.html
5. The login page is treated as though it is in /protected, so link to style.css is broken
6. I fix login.jsp so it links to relative path "../style.css" - Wow! it works, but only for resources that are one directory down.  Now it breaks for everything else.  Sigh.

It was hard to know at what level a protected resource would be.
I finally ended up using absolute paths to the CSS file and images, but
only in the login and login-error pages.